# is it possible that directly uploading local video files on azure media services?

Tags: azure-media-services

Is there a way to upload video files directly to Azure Media services?
( .net, python, CLI, API etc...)
(Except upload via portal)

I wonder how to upload files from on-prem local server (linux, windows) or Azure's virtual machine (linux, windows) to AMS.

I tested it with the command "az ams create" in the CLI, but only an empty asset is created.

The AMS REST API v2 document provides an upload method using portal and .net, but it cannot be found in the v3 document.

The attached URL is AMS REST API v2.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/previous-versions/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-upload-files

If anyone knows, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change between AMS v2 and v3 regarding how you upload the files. In v2 you used to upload files by using AMS SDKs, but, in v3 you need to upload the files by using the storage SDKs. This makes more sense as the files are being stored in the storage account, not AMS.

From the documentation here [Azure Media Services VOD Streaming code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/samples/samples-vod-streaming-reference) you can find samples in different languages and a URL to the GitHub sample.

For example, in the following .Net sample [program.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/blob/main/Streaming/StreamHLSAndDASH/Program.cs), you can search for the `CreateInputAssetAsync` function, and notice how it leverages storage SDK to upload the file into the storage blob container.